# Tomcat 8 first request processing is slow for first request

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, classloading

I'm working on a high performance java application. I deployed in Tomcat 8. First request processing is slow i.e. it is taking 800 milli seconds to process. After that every request is processing very fast within 50 milli seconds. I think for initial request class loading takes time. My requirement is performance should be high even for the first request.
My questions are:
1) How to handle this scenario?
2) Is passing a sample request after server restart is the idle way to do it?

Comment: Please let me know the browser you are using and operating system. If it is windows 7 then open cmd as administrator and run this command **netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled**

Comment: It might be because of multiple issues. Are you using spring framework or Any other DI?

Comment: No, I'm not using Spring framework or DI. I'm using Java API and JDBC.